# Why is POSIX collating-related bracketed symbol higher-precedence than backslash?

Tags: regex, posix, operator-precedence, posix-ere

POSIX, aka ["The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), has this to say about regular expression operator precedence:

> #### 9.4.8 ERE Precedence
>
> The order of precedence shall be as shown in the following table:
>
> | **ERE Precedence (from high to low)** |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | Collation-related bracket symbols | `[==] [::] [..]` |
> | Escaped characters | `\` *special-character* |
> | Bracket expression | `[]` |
> | Grouping | `()` |
> | Single-character-ERE duplication | `* + ? {m,n}` |
> | Concatenation | *ab* |
> | Anchoring | `^ $` |
> | Alternation | `|` |

I am curious as to the reason for the **first two levels** being in that order. Being a unix user from way back, I am accustomed to being able to "throw a backslash in front of it" to escape virtually anything. But it appears that with Collation-Related-Bracket-Symbols (CRBS), I can't do that. If I want to match a literal `[.ch.]` I can't just type `\[.ch.]` and rely on "dot matches dot" to handle things for me. I now have to match something like `[[].ch.]` (or possibly worse?).

I'm trying, and failing, to imagine what the scenario was when whoever-thought-this-up decided this should be the order. Is there a concrete scenario where having CRBS ranked higher than backslash makes sense, or was this a case of "we don't understand CRBS yet so let's make it higher priority" or ... what, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

At least for Gnu grep, it looks like lib/dfa.c treats the CRBS as one lexical token, as per the function `parse_bracket_exp()`.

For the example given, escaping the special characters (square brackets and dots) seems to give the results you are looking for.  You can also match literal dots with `[.]` which might be easier to see in a regular expression.

```
$ (echo c;echo '[.ch.]';echo .ch.;echo xchx)|grep '\[\.ch\.\]'
[.ch.]
```